# EXTJS Accessing Setters

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

```
Ext.define("E.model.P", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    associations: [{
        type: 'hasOne',
        model: 'E.model.D',
        associationKey: 'D',
        name:'demo',
        getterName: 'getD', // avoid dots in function name
        setterName: 'set' // avoid dots in function name
    }],
    fields: [
                { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
                { name: 'CPR', type: 'string' },


    ]



});
```

I have a Store created with the Model P

```
  var store = Ext.create("E.store.MyP");

            store.load(function() {
                store.each(function(record) {


                    var info = {
                        data: Ext.encode(record.getData()),
                        allData: Ext.encode(record.getData(true)),
                        personData: Ext.encode(record.getD()) //Here i get the getD is not a function
                    };
                    console.log(info);
                });
            });
```

The problem I am having is getD is not a function, It will only work if I do not have classes define ex: Ext.define("P").

So how do I access the getD so I can drill further down?

This works http://jsfiddle.net/aqHdC/

Now when I start seperating the classes, It stops working and says can't find function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The associated model (in your example `E.model.D`) class must be loaded for the getter to be generated.

That means you need to require this class in your base model class definition (or, as you have found out, have all your classes in the same file).

For example:

```
Ext.define("E.model.P", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    // here's for the class loader!
    requires: [
        'E.model.D'
    ],

    // rest of your definition
});
```